# Create xml Elements and sub elements in Java using dom

Tags: java, xml

I'm using Java to create an `xml` document.

I want to have the following:

```
 <epsos:asContent classCode="CONT">
    <epsos:containerPackagedMedicine classCode="CONT" determinerCode="INSTANCE">
       <epsos:name>KLARICID OD CON.R.TAB 500MG/TAB BTx6(BLIST1x6)</epsos:name>
       <epsos:formCode nullFlavor="NI"/>
       <epsos:capacityQuantity unit="1" value="6"/>
       <epsos:capTypeCode nullFlavor="NA"/>
    </epsos:containerPackagedMedicine>
 </epsos:asContent>
```

I want to create the above code using `dom`.

My current code is the one below, but `epsos:containerPackagedMedicine` is not a sub element. Do you know how to fix this?

```
NodeList nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName("manufacturedMaterial");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
   Node node = nodes.item(i);
   Element asContentEl = dom.createElement("epsos:asContent");
   asContentEl.setAttribute("code", "CONT");
   asContentEl.setNodeValue("epsos:containerPackagedMedicine");
   node.appendChild(asContentEl);
}
```

Using the above code I only get:

```
 <manufacturedMaterial classCode="MMAT" determinerCode="KIND">                                
 <epsos:asContent code="CONT"/></manufacturedMaterial>
```

Comment: I don't see `"code", "ACTI"` in your desired output.Where do you get `manufacturedMaterial`?

Comment: @CrazySabbath Yes, you are right. I will correct my question right now. `manufacturedMaterial` is an element that is already in the `xml`. I want to add elements with sub elements in this.